# jquery , selector, find, text

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have one very interesting question (for me :) )..

I'm using jquery and I want to find in HTML the first tag after my reference one .

For example my HTML :

```
    <a href="#" class="A" >A</a>
    <table>
        .....
    </table>
<a href="#" class="B" >A</a>
    <table>
        .....
    </table>
<a href="#" class="c" >A</a>
    <table>
        .....
    </table>
```

I want to select the first table after `<a href="#" class="A" >A</a>`, the first table after `<a href="#" class="B" >B</a>` ... with jquery . Because just this link is reference tag for me in HTML , all tables are the same (don't have any class, ID ...) , and I don't know how many table can be :( ..

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `next`:

```
$('a').click( function() {
    var tbl = $(this).next('table'); // find the next table element following the clicked link
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.A').next('table') // Get the next <table> element after the a.a
```

or

```
$('a.A').next() // Get the next element after the a.a
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, you can use [`+`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) to get an element directly after another element. For example, to get the table directly after the A link, you could use this:

```
$(".A + table")
```

You can also use the [`next` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Answer (score 2):

To get the table tag, use the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selector:

For example the class="A" link, to get the table:

```
$(".A").next("table");
```